# using title in view (template) in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to print title in my view (Template) in CakePHP3.

`$this->fetch('title')` is working fine in `element` and `default.ctp` but when using this in `view` it is printing nothing.

How could I print `title` in `view` using `$this->fetch('title')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view file you should assign some value to the title variable

```
$this->assign('title', 'Example title text');
```

Than in your template you should have

```
<?= $this->fetch('title') ?>
```

Comment: I want to display default title. Like if I'm accessing `login` action, the `<?= $this->fetch('title') ?>` displays `Login` in `default.ctp`. I want to display same `Login` in view(Template)

Comment: Maybe add a call to assign the title in your AppController's `beforeFilter` function. That will essentially set a default title, which you can overwrite later if required.